# Joint density function of 2 random variables - limits

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =\begin{cases}  6, \ \ x^2 \leq y \leq x \\ 0, \ \ \texttt{elsewhere} \end{cases}$$

I am trying to show that this is a joint density function, which I know how to do but I thought the x and y limits would be 0 to 1, but this doesn't lead to the double integral of 6 being 1 which it should be?

Comment: Sorry about the bad formatting - haven't quite grasped how to use LaTex yet

Comment: $$\int_0^1\left(\int_{x^2}^x6\,dy\right)dx=\ldots$$

Comment: Oh. Now I feel really stupid...thank you!